# How to match vertices to what you see in 3d

Tags: mesh

How can we make the mesh to match what we actually see in 3d?

I watched a tutorial where they only create a human form by extruding a single point as if a skeleton and around the skeleton it shows the 3d object, and I cannot make modifications like I want to it now.

https://youtube.com/watch?v=DAAwy_l4jw4&t=270s

https://youtube.com/watch?v=BXSD4LLtKfw&t=837s

I want the inner skeleton which are just  a bunch of dots connected with lines, to match the outer 3d looking body.

Comment: do you mean the tutorial uses skin modifier?

Comment: @lemon yes that one

Comment: actually i applied all the modifiers and was able to do it now, but now there is a lot of vertex congestions. how can i get rid of those congestions and make mesh much simpler there where there are soo many edges to just few

Comment: You can try a Ctrl E > Un-Subdivide, but maybe don't apply the Subdivision Surface modifier if you don't want too many vertices

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.